# How to bind data from UIspy to treeView in windows forms application

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I have window where I fetched its UI elements using UIspy. I have created a windows form application and created a treeView. What I am trying to do is I need to fetch the tree in UIspy, bind it and display in treeView in windows form application. I am a rookie and just started working on c# and windows UIA. So please elaborate how to do that

Comment: You have also recently started here at SO so welcome! Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Search for some tutorials or even the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/). Then come back with [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Cheers! :)